# Is there package to create a "Problem-Solution" environment that is symmetric for "twoside" pages?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, theorems, double-sided

## Background

The following screenshot shows a **Problem-Solution** environment that is symmetric for `twoside` papers.

**NOTE:** The problem heading is on the right side for odd-numbered pages. For even-numbered pages, the heading is on the left side.
Orphan-widow issues must also be taken into account such that there is no page break at the heading.

[image]

I already created this environment but it looks so complicated. Is there a package to do this out of the box?

## Maximal Code Snippet (I cannot minimize my code anymore)

```
\documentclass[cmyk,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,hmargin=1cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{example}[section]

\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thesection.\arabic{example}}
\newenvironment{Example}[2][]%
{%
    \refstepcounter{example}%
    %------------------- Example Head -------------------
    \par\nointerlineskip\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent%    
    \label{example:\theexample}\color{blue}%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{example:\theexample}}}%
    {%
        {\color{blue}\hrulefill}%
        \raisebox{\depth}{%
            \colorbox{blue}{%
                \color{white}Example \theexample\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\ (#1)}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    {%  
        \raisebox{\depth}{%
            \colorbox{blue}{%
                \color{white}Example \theexample\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\ (#1)}%
            }%
        }%
        {\color{blue}\hrulefill}%
    }%
    %------------------- Example Body -------------------
    \par\nopagebreak\nointerlineskip\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\noindent{\footnotesize#2}%
    %------------------- Solution Head -------------------
    \par\nointerlineskip\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \colorbox{red}{\makebox[\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{\color{white}Solution}}%
    %------------------- Solution Body -------------------
    \par\nopagebreak\nointerlineskip\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \color{red}\footnotesize\ignorespaces%
}
{%
    %------------------- Solution Foot -------------------
    \par\nopagebreak\nointerlineskip\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\noindent{\color{red}\hrulefill}%
    \par\nointerlineskip\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespacesafterend%
}

\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}
\section{Without Title}

\begin{Example}
{%
    \lipsum[1]
}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{Example}


\section{With Title}
\begin{Example}[With Title]
{%
    \lipsum[1]
}%
\lipsum[2]
\end{Example}

\section{Looping}

\multido{\ix=1+1}{10}{%
\begin{Example}[\ix]
{%
    \lipsum[\ix]
}%
Einstein's formula
\begin{equation}
E\not=mc^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[\ix]
\end{Example}\lipsum[\ix]}
\end{document}
```

Or if there is no package, could you give me a suggestion to do it in a better way?

Comment: should it completely without a pagebreak inside?

Comment: @Herbert: **Example** and **Solution** headings must be followed by at least one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the same with `tabularx` and `ragged2e` and some minor changes:

`\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}`==> `\medskip`
`\vspace{\baselineskip}`==> `\bigskip`

```
\newenvironment{Example}[2][]%
{%------------------- Example Head -------------------
    \par\bigskip\noindent%    
    \refstepcounter{example}\label{example:\theexample}%%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{example:\theexample}}}
      {\color{blue}
       \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\RaggedLeft}X @{}}
       \colorbox{blue}{\color{white}Example \theexample\ifx\relax#1\relax\else~(#1)\fi}\\\hline
       \end{tabularx}}
      {\color{blue}
       \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}X @{}}%
       \colorbox{blue}{\color{white}Example \theexample\ifx\relax#1\relax\else~(#1)\fi}\\\hline
       \end{tabularx}}%
    %------------------- Example Body -------------------
    \par\nopagebreak\nointerlineskip\medskip
       \noindent{\footnotesize#2}%
    %------------------- Solution Head -------------------
    \par\nointerlineskip\medskip\noindent%
    \colorbox{red}{\makebox[\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{\color{white}Solution}}%
    %------------------- Solution Body -------------------
    \par\nopagebreak%\nointerlineskip\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \color{red}\footnotesize\ignorespaces%
}
{%------------------- Solution Foot -------------------
    \par\nopagebreak\nointerlineskip\medskip
         \noindent{\color{red}\hrulefill}%
    \par\nointerlineskip\bigskip\noindent\ignorespacesafterend%
}
```

Comment: The first `\noindent` in Solution does not work the way I want. You commented out the line. :-)

Comment: Why did you remove the first `\nointerlineskip` (after Example Head) ?

Comment: @xport: by mistake ...

Comment: Thanks for the modification. I like your modification: `\ifx...\fi`, `\bigskip`, and `\medskip`. I use them.

Answer (score 0):

The [Memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) document class has `\ifodd` macro for testing whether you're on an odd page. You could do this to have the section headings display differently depending on whether you're on an odd or even page. See p. 338 of the [memoir manual](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)

The code is adapted from the [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changepage/) package, so I guess you could use that instead.